# Writing unit test for service function

Tags: java, unit-testing

I need some help to write test for the below method in the service layer. I am not sure how to mock those methods (in DAO as wells as in same service layer) in Mockito for this service. Before that I think I should mock whole for loop to avoid mocking of each of those methods. What is the proper way to write unit test for such method.

```
public List<CheckupHistoryDto> getCaseHistory(Individual patient, Individual doctor) {
    List<CheckupHistoryDto> checkupHistoryList = new ArrayList<ClaimHistoryDto>();
    List<CaseHistory> caseHistoryIds = caseDetailDao.fetchCaseIds(patient.getId(), doctor.getId());
    for(CaseHistory caseHistory : caseHistoryIds) {
        CheckupHistoryDto checkupHistoryDto = new CheckupHistoryDto();
        checkupHistoryDto.setDateOfCall(formatter.format(caseHistory.getCreateDate()));
        checkupHistoryDto.setPatientInfo(getPatientInfo(patient));
        checkupHistoryDto.setDoctorInfo(getDoctorInfo(doctor));
        checkupHistoryDto.setServiceProvided(caseDetailDao.fetchServiceHistory(caseHistory.getEventId()));
        checkupHistoryList.add(checkupHistoryDto);
    }
    return checkupHistoryList;
}

public Patient getPatientInfo(patient) {
    ...
}

public Doctor getDoctorInfo(doctor) {
    ...
}
```

And my test case

```
@Test
public void testHistoryList() {
  Individual patient = Mockito.mock(Individual.class);
  Individual doctor= Mockito.mock(Individual.class);
  List<CheckupHistoryDto> checkupHistory = caseService.getCaseHistory(patient, doctor);
  assertEquals(MOCK_LIST_SIZE, checkupHistory.size());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about "mocking the for loop", that makes no sense since it is part of the functionality you want to test; specifically, when you unit test class XQ, you never mock any portion of class XQ.

you need to mock the following:

1. Individual.getId for the patient.
2. Individual.getId for the doctor.
3. whatever methods on the Individual class that are used by `getPatientInfo` method, for the patient.
4. whatever methods on the Individual class that are used by the `getDoctorInfo` method, for the doctor.
5. caseDetailDao.fetchCaseIDs
6. caseDetailDao.fetchServiceHistory
7. caseHistory.getCreateDate, if you return a list of mock objects from  fetchCaseIds.
8. caseHistory.getEventId, if you return a list of mock objects from  fetchCaseIds.

You have some terrible code:

1. caseHsitory.fetchCaseIds is clearly not returning caseIDs, it is returning case details.